# WinSCP error 5 Access Denied while downloading via command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp, winscp

I am trying to copy all files and folders from the "My Documents" directory from one Windows machine to another, but I receive an error of "Access Denied". I have set full access permission to users on both machines.

My command:

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "get C:\Users\nohupt\Documents\* /users/nohupt/Documents/" ^
    "exit"
```

And the error:

> Can't open file 'c:\users\nohupt\Documents\desktop.ini'.
>   System Error. Code 5.
>   Access is Denied
>   Copying files from remote side failed.
>   (A)bort, (R)etry, (S)kip, Ski(p) all: Abort

How do I allow access and how do I work around WinSCP prompts?

Comment: How do you run your command?

Comment: pasting command into command line, but ultimately want to run via task scheduler

Comment: What if you do `copy c:\users\nohupt\Documents\desktop.ini %TEMP%`? Does it succeed?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes, it succeeds.

Comment: What version of WinSCP are you using?

Comment: version 5.13.4  -- i've actually switched to using synchronize command but still getting access denied errors even though folders are set to full access for the user :-/

Answer (score 0):

You have the [`get` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get) arguments backwards. It should be `get <remote> <local>`:

```
"get /users/nohupt/Documents/* C:\Users\nohupt\Documents\" ^
```

Comment: Can you download the files in WinSCP GUI?

Comment: Yea, it runs fine in the GUI. I can also run synchronize from command line manually, but have permission problems on most files and folders even though they are set to full access on both machines. I'm assuming because some of them are open, but most are not, so I'm confused.

Comment: So please post a log file from GUI and script showing a successful and failed download of the same files.

Answer (score 0):

if the destination file is hidden winscp.com will throw error code 5. from the gui it will run fine.